# Solving complex equation using half angle formula

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve the following equation: $z^2 + (1 + i)z - 2 - i = 0$ using half angle formula.

I solved the equation and got the roots $z = 1$ and $z = -2 - i$.  However, the question says to use the half angle formulas.  I am not sure how to use this formula and when I try it seems to get quite convoluted so I am no sure what the point of using it is if there are other ways to solve the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is evident that
$$z^2 + (1 + i)z - 2 - i=(z-1)(z+2+i)$$
and therefore you are correct. But try to apply the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). Then the roots of the polynomial are
$$\frac{-(1+i)\pm\sqrt{(1+i)^2+4(2+i)}}{2}=\frac{-1-i\pm\sqrt{8+6i}}{2}.$$
In order to find the **complex** square roots of $8+6i$, you may use the half angle formulas. We have that
$$8+6i=10(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$$
and therefore $\cos(\theta)=4/5$ and $\sin(\theta)=3/5$. Now you need to compute
$$\sqrt{10}(\cos(\theta/2)+i\sin(\theta/2))=
\sqrt{10}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{2}}+i\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{2}}\right).$$
The other square root has opposite sign (see the $\pm$ sign in the quadratic formula).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's where I get stuck.  I am not sure how to go about implementing 8 + 6i with the half angle formulas in order to find the complex square roots.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you very much.  I seemed to be getting something confused with the trig signs, however, now it makes more sense.  Thank you very much.